# Rust OOP - Polymorphism limitation of a trait bound element of a vector of a struct

Tags: multithreading, oop, rust, polymorphism, rust-tokio

I am working on a project where I would like to stream data from two data sources in separate threads but run into the following error:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method
  --> client_runner/src/lib.rs:37:23
   |
15 |     pub async fn run(&mut self) {
   |                      ---------
   |                      |
   |                      `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
   |                      let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
37 |         for client in self.clients.iter() {
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                       |
   |                       `self` escapes the method body here
   |                       argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

As I understand it has to do with the fact that `clients` is a member of `self` and is being borrowed here for the method `run`. I'm not really sure what to do to make this right. I have tried using a for loop that iterates over the size of the vector and then access the clients via `self.clients[idx].stream()` but this does not work when I try to launch it as a tokio task. If I do not launch them in a tokio task each client runs fine but now they are running synchronously.

I understand there are limitations to Rust's OOP capabilities but I am a programmer coming from Java, C++, and some python so OOP is all I know. If anyone can offer a "Rusty" way of doing this task that makes more sense for the ownership model I am open to it.

I am very new to rust so please let me know if I am doing anything incorrect or if I can do something better. I take this as an opportunity to learn from my mistakes.

See code below:

**crate main_project**

main.rs

```
use client_runner::*;
use data_sources::{
    DataSource,
    source1_interface::Source1Client,
    source2_interface::Source2Client,
};

#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread")]
async fn main() {
    // Create the vector of clients
    let client_list: Vec<Box<dyn DataSource + Send + Sync>> = vec! [
        Box::new(Source1Client::new()),
        Box::new(Source2Client::new()),
    ];
    
    // Take in a vector of clients to launch in their own threads
    let mut client_runner = ClientRunner::new(client_list);
    client_runner.run().await;
}
```

**crate client_runner**

lib.rs

```
use data_sources::DataSource;
use std:thread;

pub struct ClientRunner {
    clients: Vec<Box<dyn DataSource + Send + Sync>>,
}

impl ClientRunner {
    /// Creates a new Client Runner given a list of clients that implement the DataSource trait
    pub fn new(client_list: Vec<Box<dyn DataSource + Send + Sync>>) -> Self {
        ClientRunner {clients: client_list}
    }

    pub async fn run(&mut self) {
        println!("Main Thread: {:?}", thread::current().id());
        // Single call works but is not multithreaded
        // self.clients[0].stream().await;
        
        // Error here
        for client in self.clients.iter() {
            // Launch worker threads to:
            // Stream the data
            tokio::task::spawn(async move {
                client.stream().await;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**crate data_sources**

lib.rs

```
use async_trait::async_trait;

#[async_trait]
pub trait DataSource {
    asyn fn stream(&self);
}

pub mod source1_interface;
pub mod source2_interface;
```

source1_interface.rs

```
pub struct Source1Client{
    ...
}

unsafe impl Send for Source1Client {}
unsafe impl Sync for Source1Client {}

#[async_trait]
impl DataSource for Source1Client {
    async fn stream(&self) {
        println!("Streaming Source1 Data on thread: {:?}", thread::current().id());
    }
}

impl Source1Client {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        ...
        Source1Client {
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

source2_interface.rs

```
pub struct Source2Client{
    ...
}

unsafe impl Send for Source2Client {}
unsafe impl Sync for Source2Client {}

#[async_trait]
impl DataSource for Source2Client {
    async fn stream(&self) {
        println!("Streaming Source2 Data on thread: {:?}", thread::current().id());
    }
}

impl Source2Client {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        ...
        Source2Client {
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE - POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I have found that I can use the `Arc` smart pointer instead of the `Box` smart pointer. According to the `Arc` documentation:
[https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#:~:text='Arc'%20stands%20for%20'Atomically,while%20increasing%20a%20reference%20count.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#:%7E:text=%27Arc%27%20stands%20for%20%27Atomically,while%20increasing%20a%20reference%20count.)

The type `Arc<T>` provides shared ownership of a value of type `T`, allocated in the heap. Invoking clone on `Arc` produces a new `Arc` instance, which points to the same allocation on the heap as the source `Arc`, while increasing a reference count.

This gets me around the issue of borrowed data escaping since it is shared.

I invite anyone to present a more "Rusty" solution. See the code below:

**crate main_project**

main.rs

```
...

#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread")]
async fn main() {
    // Create the vector of clients
    let client_list: Vec<Arc<dyn DataSource + Send + Sync>> = vec! [
        Arc::new(Source1Client::new()),
        Arc::new(Source2Client::new()),
    ];
    
    ...
}
```

**crate client_runner**

lib.rs

```
...
use std::sync::Arc;

pub struct ClientRunner {
    clients: Vec<Arc<dyn DataSource + Send + Sync>>,
}

impl ClientRunner {
    pub fn new(client_list: Vec<Arc<dyn DataSource + Send + Sync>>) -> Self {
        ClientRunner { clients: client_list }
    }

    pub async fn run(&mut self) {
        println!("Main Thread: {:?}", thread::current().id());
        
        let mut worker_threads = Vec::new();
        for idx in 0..self.clients.len() {
            // Launch worker threads to:
            // Stream the data
            let moved_client = Arc::clone(&self.clients[idx]);
            let task_handle = tokio::task::spawn(async move {
                moved_client.stream().await;
            });
            worker_threads.push(task_handle);
        }
 
        // Join the threads
        for thread in worker_threads {
            tokio::join!(thread);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to emulate OOP in Rust. You are going to have a Bad Time.

Comment: It is the only way my mind is currently thinking about the problem. Is there another model I should follow for Rust that could solve this problem? @AleksanderKrauze

Answer (score 1):

There are two orthogonal questions here.

First, the error is unrelated to anything about OOP, traits, etc.; it occurs specifically because references to elements of `self.clients` are captured by a closure that itself escapes the method because of `tokio::task::spawn_blocking`, whose argument has a `'static` bound. Here's a minimal reproduction without trait objects:

```rust
struct Foo {
    v: Vec<String>,
}

impl Foo {
    async fn bar(&self) {
        for s in self.v.iter() {
            tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
                println!("{s}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler output:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method
 --> src/main.rs:9:18
  |
8 |     async fn bar(&self) {
  |                  -----
  |                  |
  |                  `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
  |                  let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
9 |         for s in self.v.iter() {
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                  |
  |                  `self` escapes the method body here
  |                  argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0521`.
```

As you note in your update, using `Arc<T>` over `Box<T>` works because the `Arc<T>` can be cloned and moved by value into the closure.

---

With regard to the OOP aspect of your question, this particular use case -- using trait objects to abstract across different trait implementations -- is perfectly idiomatic Rust. The big "missing" OOP feature in Rust is inheritance, which as far as I can tell isn't a factor in your question.<sup>1</sup>

With regard to trait method dispatch, using sum types (Rust `enum`s) is typically preferred over trait objects where possible, as it does not require heap allocation.<sup>2</sup> Using an enum for your case looks like:

```
enum Client {
    Source1(Source1Client),
    Source2(Source2Client),
}

impl Client {
    async fn stream(&self) {
        match self {
            Client::Source1(cl) => cl.stream(),
            Client::Source2(cl) => cl.stream(),
        }
    }
}

pub struct ClientRunner {
    clients: Vec<Client>,
}

// etc.
```

...and the rest of the code looks pretty much the same as you already have it.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The Rust Book has [a section on how Rust accomplishes the goals of inheritance with other mechanisms](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-01-what-is-oo.html#inheritance-as-a-type-system-and-as-code-sharing).</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Manually dispatching method calls with an `enum` also allows the compiler to inline more aggressively and invoke the method with less overhead, although the gains from this are insignificant unless the method body executes very quickly (think microseconds) and there are many such calls in a tight loop.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tend to not use the full power of Enums in Rust but hopefully working through this will give me a better understanding so I can add to my arsenal of Rust knowledge. I will give the Enum a try and see how well it works for my scenario.